# Regular expression fails to match the plus sign ('+') in Angular 2, but it works fine in testers

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

Here is the code:

```
export const PASSWORD_PATTERN: RegExp = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9`~!@#$%^&*()\-_+={[}\]|\\:;"'<,>.?/]{8,}$/;
```

This variable is being used like this elsewhere:

```
Validators.pattern(PASSWORD_PATTERN);
```

The intention is for this code to validate passwords by making sure that they contain one lowercase letter, one uppercase letter, and one number. Passwords may contain any number of special characters, and those characters are the ones that can be found on a standard keyboard (e.g. ~ * ( } ; + ). As of now, the regular expression will match passwords containing every single special character except for the plus sign ('+'). I've tried replacing '+' with '\+' and '\\+' in the regex, but that hasn't changed the result. At one point, I got rid of every special character in the regex except for the plus sign, to test it by itself, and once again using '+', '\+', and '\\+' in the regex wouldn't produce any matches for passwords containing a plus sign.

Using the regexp I pasted earlier, this password is considered a match:

```
Password1`~!@#$%^&*()-_=[{]}\|;:'",<.>/?
```

While this password isn't considered a match:

```
Password1`~!@#$%^&*()-_=[{]}\|;:'",<.>/?+
```

The only difference between those two passwords is the single plus sign at the end, and the second password isn't a match whether the regex contains +, \+, or \\+.

The regular expression is working completely on the backend, though it has been modified for the language being used primarily on the backend.

Comment: There is no harm in escaping the forward slash inside the special char class: `/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9\`~!@#$%^&*()\-_+={[}\]|\\:;"'<,>.?\/]{8,}$/`

Comment: I ran a code snippet with your regex and the pwd with/without the +. Seemed to work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when I was appending the password to parameters I needed to wrap it in the encodeURIcomponent() method. Not sure why, but now all of the regular expression patterns I create are now working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest thing, but this seems to work (or at least go in the right direction):

```js
let characters = /((.*[A-Z])((.*[a-z].*\d)|(.*\d.*[a-z])).*)|((.*[a-z])((.*[A-Z].*\d)|(.*\d.*[A-Z])).*)|((.*\d)((.*[a-z].*[A-Z])|(.*[A-Z].*[a-z])).*)/;
let length = /.{8,}/;

let good1 = 'abc+Def8';
let good2 = '8b2cDde+';
let bad1 = 'abc+def8';
let bad2 = 'Ab+cde';
let bad3 = 'ab+cD2'

console.log(characters.test(good1) && length.test(good1), characters.test(good2) && length.test(good2), characters.test(bad1) && length.test(bad1), characters.test(bad2) && length.test(bad2), characters.test(bad3) && length.test(bad3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Testing it using [this site](http://regexr.com/), and the JS code at the bottom it looks like it is working. How are you testing to make sure the passwords are valid?

In the new regEx I changed all the symbols to `[\S]`.  That will match all chars that are not whitespace. Do you want to limit the passwords to just special chars that are on are normally used on a keyboard, or all of the possible ones? If so you should use the `[\S]`. Infact there is no real reason why you shouldn't allow all characters (except end line) in a password. In which case you should replace `[\S]` with `.`.

How are you handling the password value? Are you passing it to the back end in plain text? A nice way to handle it might be to check if the password matched the regex you have on the front end, hash the password using sha-256 (and salt it with a unique user string if you want to go nice and overkill), then pass that back the the server. The server would then salt and hash the password again before storing it in a table to be compared to when the user logs in next.

This helps add an extra layer of security for the user. Assuming you are using a ssl connection between the user and the server this is not really needed (ALWAYS USE SSL), but it is always nice to be a little more on the safe side when it comes to users passwords. That being said this will not prevent someone from logging in as a user if they get a successful man in the middle attack off, because when hashing a password user side it just becomes the validation that is sent to the server and validated against. However, this avoids you ever having knowledge of the users actual password, so if someone does intercept the hash (or say the server leaks some of its pre server side hashing data. Looking at you heartbleed!) someone can't easily go a bunch of other sites and try the user's username/password combo.

```js
const regEx = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[\S]{8,}$/;

const good1 = 'A12345678a+'
const good2 = 'Aaascfsfas1@#$@+#$%'
const example1 = 'Password1`~!@#$%^&*()-_=[{]}\|;:",<.>/?'
const example2 = 'Password1`~!@#$%^&*()-_=[{]}\|;:",<.>/?+'
const bad1 = 'a'
const bad2 = 'aasdfasfdsfads@+#$%$#@'

console.log(
regEx.test(good1), regEx.test(good2), 
regEx.test(example1), regEx.test(example2), 
regEx.test(bad1), regEx.test(bad2)
)
```